# file.seek()/write() in main process and file.flush() in thread

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-asyncio

I've opened a file with `open(..., 'r+b')`, is it safe to call `.flush()` in a thread while the main process is performing `.read()`/`.write()`/`.seek()` operations on this file in Python 3.6+?

The goal is to be able to read/write quickly using the buffer but to offload the flush into a thread (assuming it is the most expensive operation).

Any other tips or gotchas with this approach?

Comment: See http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/fsync-different-thread-useless.html, f/e, re: `fsync()` on a different thread being useless. Admittedly, this isn't the same thing as `flush()` -- `fsync()` ensures content is flushed *to disk* (and survives a reboot), whereas `flush()` ensures it's flushed *to the OS* (and visible to other processes) -- but there can be similar issues in play (depending on how your libc manages its buffers).

Comment: ...it would be a lot more straightforward to put the content you're writing onto a queue, and have a separate thread read from the queue, write to the sink, *and* flush. That way you aren't depending on any semantics that aren't well-documented.

Comment: (To be clear, a `.write()` to a buffered stream that isn't long enough to trigger a `flush()` automatically, and doesn't otherwise trigger a write -- as by containing a newline if the stream is line-buffered -- isn't actually doing any OS-level work at all: it's just appending content to a buffer, managed by the local libc, that's going to be written later, on flush or close).